# How to create a bridging table between DbContext and IdentityDbContext?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I want to create a bridging table between `dbo.AspNetUsers` and `dbo.Recipe` called `dbo.Binder`. A user can save many recipes and a recipe can be saved by many users (many-to-many).

I'm able to create bridging tables within my `DbContext` fine, called `RecipeContext`, e.g `dbo.Recipe`, `dbo.TagRecipe` and `dbo.Tag`, but I am confused how I'm suppose to do this between two different `DbContext`s, that being `RecipeContext` (`DbContext`) and  `ApplicationDbContext(IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>)`.

One solution I read was for `RecipeContext` to  inherit from `IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>`, like so:

```
public class RecipeContext :IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
```

Though when I do this and run

```
Update-Database -Context RecipeContext
```

I get an error

> There is already an object named `AspNetRoles` in the database

I suppose this is from when I had the contexts separate, and yes, the `AspNetRoles`/identity tables are already created in my database from before.

I'm wondering if for one, I'm on the right track and two, what do I do about the fact the Identity tables already exist?

Thank you

For reference

`RecipeContext`:

```
public class RecipeContext :IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser> /*: DbContext*/
{
    public RecipeContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TagRecipe> TagRecipes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StarRating> StarRatings { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Binder> Binders { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // Identity
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        ...(code left out)

        // Override pural table names to singular 
        modelBuilder.Entity<Binder>().ToTable("Binder");

        // Declare use UserId and RecipeId as primary keys for Binder
        modelBuilder.Entity<Binder>()
            .HasKey(b => new { b.UserId, b.RecipeId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Binder>()
            .HasOne<ApplicationUser>(b => b.User)
            .WithMany(u => u.Binders)
            .HasForeignKey(b => b.UserId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Binder>()
            .HasOne<Recipe>(b => b.Recipe)
            .WithMany(u => u.Binders)
            .HasForeignKey(b => b.RecipeId);
    }
}
```

`ApplicationDbContext` (this is to be merged into `RecipeContext`):

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

Binder class:

```
public class Binder
{
    public string UserId { get; set; } 
    public int RecipeId { get; set; } 
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; } 
    public Recipe Recipe { get; set; } 
}
```

`ApplicationUser` class (this was self created to create a collection of Binders)

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ICollection<Binder> Binders { get; set; }
}
```

`Recipe` class:

```
public class Recipe
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    ...(code left out)

    public ICollection<Binder> Binders { get; set; }
}
```

`Startup` class - `ConfigureServices` method (I feel some adjustments will need to be made if the two dbContexts are merging)

```
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Identity
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options =>
        {
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;

            // Password settings.
            options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

            // Lockout settings.
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
            options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

            // User settings.
            options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
            "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
        })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        services.AddControllersWithViews()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        );
        services.AddRazorPages(); // Added - Identity scaffhold Views

        // Recipe context
        services.AddDbContext<RecipeContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
        });

    }
```

`appsettings.json`:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=WCIMDBCoreEF1ModelTest;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
    "ApplicationDbContextConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=MVCApp;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
}
```

Comment: I believe that DbContext is usually mapped to one database, multiple DbContexts should be mapped to different databases ***OR*** the tables (entity types) should not overlap. Otherwise it will be very complicated to handle the data migrations. That's the point. As long as you can avoid overlapped tables, you're good to go. If you cannot avoid that, you should rephrase your original issue to find another approach.

Comment: Syntax aside, I wouldn't link business DbSet (Recipe, in your example) and Identity provider. In fact, I would not access AspNetUsers table directly at all... I would just have UserId field in Recipe object; and save user id there (GUID or login) as you are saving the recipe